# purrr::pluck() and purrr::map() with second argument of type double

Tags: r, purrr

This is related to [Chapter 9.2.6, Exercise 2](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#exercises-28) in *Advanced R* by Hadley Wickham.

I cannot explain the behavior of the purrr functions `pluck()` and `map()` in combination with certain double values in the second argument.

```
# pluck with index of type `double`
pluck(1:3, -2.3456)   # returns 1
pluck(1:3, 2.9876)    # returns 2

# map with vector of type `double`
map(1:3, runif(2))    # returns list(1, 2, 3)
```

Why do we get these results?

Answer (score 2):

For your first example `pluck(1:3, -2.3456)`, if you look at the [c source code of pluck](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/blob/main/src/pluck.c) it has

```
if (val < 0) {
      val = n + val + 1;
    }
```

So for negative indexes, it subtracts the value from the total number of elements and adds 1. This makes sense, for example if you are looking for index -2 (second from the right) of a three element list, it would look for index 3 + -2 + 1, which equals 2 (the second from the right). For your example it would be 3 + -2.3456 + 1 = 1.6544

`pluck(1:3, 1.6544)` is 1, because pluck emulates `[[` and per [The R documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing-by-vectors) when you index with non-integer values: `Non-integer values are converted to integer (by truncation towards zero) before use.`

Similarly for your second example, 2.9876 gets truncated to 2.

I don't know about your third example.

Comment: The third example is answered [here](https://advanced-r-solutions.rbind.io/functionals.html).

Comment: I am happy with the nice explanation for the first two examples. Instead of the third example we could also look at pluck(1:3, 0.1234), which gives 1

Comment: @Julian I looked at that answer which starts out well when it says the map function gets turned into something like `pluck(x, 0.6863541, 0.8791763, .default = NULL)` by `as_mapper`, which I follow, but then says "This leads to three NULLs (pluck()’s .default return), because no values corresponding to the index can be found." I also get that, but how do three NULLs then get turned into `list(1, 2, 3)`?